# Popup form post prevent site from refresh

Tags: asp.net-mvc, post, popup

I have a kendo grid with a button in it. When the button is pressed it opens up a popup with a file-select input and a button so that the user can save a image. Im using a normal form with a submit button to post my form to my controller. Everything works fine the right data arrives to the controller but then the page refreshes. I just want the popup to close and the grid and the whole page behind the popup to just stay as it is. Here is my controller:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult SaveData(HttpPostedFileBase file, string id)
    {
        iResourceModel.SaveData(file, file.FileName);
        return null;
    }
```

and my html form:

```
 <div id="details-container">
 <form action="/Home/SaveData" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
 <span>Select file:</span><input type="file" name="file" id="file">
 <input type="text" value=' + dataItem.ResourceId +' name="id" id="id" hidden/>
 <button type="submit" id="" >Save file</button>
 </form>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Page reloading after submitting a form is normal behavior. If you want to stop it, you can use jQuery and submit the form in the background.

You can find the jQuery form plugin here : http://plugins.jquery.com/form/

For your case :

```
<div id="details-container">
 <form action="/Home/SaveData" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="myForm">
 <span>Select file:</span><input type="file" name="file" id="file">
 <input type="text" value=' + dataItem.ResourceId +' name="id" id="id" hidden/>
 <button type="submit" id="" >Save file</button>
 </form>
 </div>
 <script> 

    $(document).ready(function() { 

        $('#myForm').ajaxForm(function() { 
            alert("File uploaded!"); 
        }); 
    }); 
</script>
```

Comment: How does the .ajaxForm know where to post the data? And what parameters do i need to have in my controller for it to be able to get the data?